# Sass refuses to compile on Linux Fedora 36

Tags: linux, npm, sass, fedora

SASS refuses to compile on Linux Fedora 36. When I try to compile it into CSS via the sass command (which is installed globally via npm) , the terminal "freezes" and nothing happens. I've also tried to compile it via a VScode extention and that also doesn't work , as the extension doesn't even "boot up" when I click "watch Sass". It does work on Windows however, so this problem is only limited to Fedora. Intrestingly enough, it worked just fine for a couple of days and only stopped a few hours , after I wrote this post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should re-install Node and sass both.

And make sure you install dart-sass specifically.

To install dart-sass, you just need to run `npm install -g sass` and it will install dart-sass(named as sass on npm).